# Generating a doc file from a php "results" page?

Tags: php, html, file, generated

I have a PHP generated page containing the results of a submitted form, what I would like to do is save this as a .doc file on the server.
After some googling I came across this code which I adapted:-

```
$myFile = "./dump/".$companyName."/testFile.doc";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

But the problem with this is that I would have to recreate the results in order to manually write them to the file and it doesn't seem very efficient.

So I continued to google and found the PHP manual which left me scratching my head frankly, however I eventually found this:-

```
ob_start();
// code to generate page.
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// or write it to a file.
file_put_contents("./dump/".$companyName."/testFile.doc",$out);
```

Which will create the file, but doesn't write anything to it. However this seems to be the way to do what (Based on the PHP manual) I want even if I can't get it to work!

Any advice? I don't mind googling if I can figure out a decent search term :)

Comment: Your code works fine in my env. Are you `echo`'ing or printing the values between ob_start and ob_get_contents?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "recreate the results"; and why is this, as you say, inefficient?

Comment: Cwallenpoole - Not echoing anything, what's there is what I'm trying to use. Thanks Awea I will read through that thread. Bosworth99 - By inefficient I mean that I will have to write out each of the $_post results individually again - I have already created a table to display each of them. It's doable using this method but seems clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sould do it for you:

```
$cache = 'path/to/your/file';

ob_start();

// your content goes here...
echo "hello !"; // would put hello into your file

$page = ob_get_contents(); 

ob_end_clean(); 

$fd = fopen("$cache", "w"); 

    if ($fd) {

    fwrite($fd,$page); 

    fclose($fd);

}
```

It's also a great way to cache dynamic pages. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but aside from creating the file, this doesn't seem to write anything to it?

Comment: where it says `//your content goes here` you can write anything you want. `echo/print` entire pages.

Comment: Sorry : this `fwrite($fd,$pages);` needs to be `fwrite($fd,$page);`

Comment: Ah ha...That explains why it didn't write hello! So using this method I would need to copy the content of the BODY where it says your content goes here? Thanks again

Comment: Copy/ Include the script around the part you want copied. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: To make this work I added a new stage between submitting the form and viewing the results this created a .html (instead of the doc) file that I included in the final stage. So thanks, I have learned a new approach today :)